# How can I create a .p12 or .pfx file without a private key?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I'm trying to create a .p12 file that does not contain a valid identity (public key / private key pair) in order to test my app's certificate import functionality. Is it possible to do this with the `openssl` tool?

I've tried

```bash
openssl pkcs12 -in client-certonly.pem -export -out client-certonly.p12
```

but I get an error:

`unable to load private key`
`471:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

If it isn't possible to do this with `openssl`, is there another tool I can use?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is a very handy GUI tool written in java called [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) which you can use for creation of an empty PKCS#12 keystore and also for an import of the certificate without the private key into the PKCS#12 keystore - this functionality is available under "Import trusted certificate (Ctrl-T)" button.

However if you insist on using OpenSSL you can use this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in certificate.cer -out pkcs12.pfx
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you know if it's possible to do this with `openssl`?

Comment: * Note! On windows machine, you have to run open ssl as an admin

Comment: I'm getting `unable to load certificates`.

Comment: Apparently Java doesn't like the format this command produces, so if you are using this for a Java truststore here's the equivalent `keytool` command: `keytool -import -alias mycert -file certificate.cer -keystore truststore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass password`

Comment: I have the same issue as @Ozkan and I'm afraid the suggestion by @nerdherd didn't work for me... then again, I'm not sure what that command is supposed to be doing. I have no need to import my `CER` certificate into any Java truststore (sorry, I'm not a Java programmer and haven't got the slightest clue about what that might be or where it is located...), but rather get a PKCS#12 file. `keytool -printcert -file mycert.cer` certainly works, though — with the expected result (i.e. displaying the content of my standalone `CER` certificate).

Comment: While this works, the truststore is unusable with Java. sun.security.pkcs12.KCS12KeyStore requires all trust certs to have the following bag attribute: `{ joint-iso-itu-t(2) country(16) us(840) organization(1) oracle(113894) jdk(746875) crypto(1) id-at-trustedKeyUsage(1)`

Comment: Is it possible to create privatekey if you have cer without it?

Comment: (@Michael-O) if you (have and consistently) use the _BouncyCastle_ provider it does not require the Oracle-proprietary attribute; it _does_ require friendlyname which `openssl pkcs12 -export` doesn't put by default on cert not matching a privatekey but you can use `-caname $x`

Comment: I use the [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) tool, which allows me to create it by UI. **But** I needed a command (automation), and using the post command when I open the resulting `p12` in the tool, it is empty. The `keytool` command by @nerdherd worked.

Comment: same problem as @lucasvc - it seems we have to use keytool to create a (portable) .p12 file without a private key/with only the public key|certificate entry

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has problem and get error message "unable to load certificates", try this approach:

```
openssl.exe x509 -inform der -in "C:\Temp\myfile.cer" -out "c:\Temp\myfile.pem"

openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out "c:\Temp\myfile.pfx" -nokeys -in "c:\Temp\myfile.pem"
```