# How to create pkcs12 truststore using openssl

Tags: openssl, keystore, keytool, pkcs#12

I can export a Java truststore (JKS file with *only* certificates, *no* private key), using the keytool command to a p12 file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore truststore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how I could create the same file using the 'openssl pkcs12' command.  It allows you to pass in certificates, but every option I've tried requires the user to pass in the private key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a .p12 file without a private key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935820/how-can-i-create-a-p12-file-without-a-private-key)

Answer (score 21):

`openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in certificate.cer -out pkcs12.pfx`