# Security of p12 (PKCS#12) certificate format

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, pkcs#12

I have a question for the PKCS#12 format. The strange part is it requires to provide private key and the private key will be kept in the generated file.

Normally, when we apply a certificate from CA, we usually generate a CSR which contains the public key of a key pair I generated in advance. This public key will be put in the Certificate. So, when initiate the SSL connection, it will be used to encrypt and transmit the symmetric encryption key for the rest SSL channel communication. Since MITM don’t know the private key, so, they cannot get the symmetric encryption key. Only server has the private key can decrypt.

So, in any case, we should NOT put server’s certificate private key to others. Now, if I put the private key to PKCS#12, it seems totally breaks the rule.

I am working on a project related with a SSL pinning. A legacy lib requires to use PKCS#12 file format as the input. I feel it is very insecure to put the p12 certificate at client app.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Whats's the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a .p12 file without a private key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935820/how-can-i-create-a-p12-file-without-a-private-key)