# Creating .p12 truststore with openssl

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I'm writing a Java 8 application and want to set up a simple keystore and truststore using a self-signed certificate.

Normally this goes as follows:

1. Create a keypair + certificate using `openssl`.
2. Create a .jks keystore + .jks truststore using `keytool`

Now I'd like to only use `openssl` and create .p12 keystores instead of .jks keystores.

Creating a .p12 keystore works great using the following commands:

```
# Create private key and certificate
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:"${rsa}" -sha256 \
    -keyout "${key}" \
    -out "${cert}" \
    -days "${days}"

# Create .p12 keystore
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "${cert}" -inkey "${key}" -out "${keystore}"
```

This keystore seems to be working correctly, as providing a corresponding .jks trustore in my Java application will get the TLS connection going. However I can't get a .p12 truststore working.

I tried creating the truststore as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941513/3620458):

```
# Create .p12 truststore
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in "${cert}" -out "${truststore}"
```

and then loading it like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(trustorePath));
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
trustStore.load(fis, truststorePassword.toCharArray());
fis.close();
```

but I receive the following exception in my java code:

> Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
>   the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

(A working snippet using .p12 truststore with Java 8 would be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: Truststores usually do not cointain private keys. May be that is confusing Java? remove the private key if not needed or add the certificate without private key a second time.

Comment: i tried your snipped and it worked using openssl 0.9.8zh and oracle jdk 1.8.0_121, it's strange

Comment: `keytool` may be an easier tool to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A possible explanation for this behaviour:

> The standard PKCS#12 provider up to Java 7 did not allow trusted
> certificate entries at all. The JSSE Reference Guide says this:
>
> Storing trusted certificates in a PKCS12 keystore is not supported.
> PKCS12 is mainly used to deliver private keys with the associated
> certificate chains. It does not have any notion of "trusted"
> certificates. In terms of interoperability, other PKCS12 vendors have
> the same restriction. Browsers such as Mozilla and Internet Explorer
> do not accept a PKCS12 file with only trusted certificates.
>
> This has changed a bit in Java 8, which supports trusted certificates
> in PKCS#12 - if they are marked with a special attribute (OID
> 2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1):
>
> ```
> openssl pkcs12 -in microsoft.p12 -info
> MAC Iteration 1024
> MAC verified OK
> PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
> Certificate bag
> Bag Attributes
>     friendlyName: microsoft it ssl sha2 (baltimore cybertrust root)
>     2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>
> ```

Source:

- https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer/issues/35
- https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer/issues/11

Comment: I am on "1.8.0_171" and this magic attribute is no longer required. All entries added to PKCS12 store are trusted when used in a trust manager.

Comment: I am on "1.8.0_171" and this is not working, PKCS12 containing only certificates give the "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty" error

Comment: I am on "11.0.14.1" and PKCS12 files containing only certificates are still not properly loaded.

Comment: How can we add this magic attribute?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found the way to do it with openssl, though I've found the way to do it with keytool (a part of OpenJDK suite).

I needed to create a keystore which would contain the CA certificate with the `2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>` attribute and an additional certificate and its key without this attribute. I'd like to share the solution with other people who will find this page by googling `openssl  "2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1"` :-)

This command creates a PKCS12 with the CA certificate (assuming you already have a CA) which has `2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>` attribute:

```
keytool -storepass '***' -import -alias ca -file ***/ca.crt.pem -keystore ***/ca.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

This command converts the additional PEM-encoded certificate and its private key to PKCS12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ***/additional.cert.pem -inkey ***/additional.key.pem -name additional -export -out ***/additional.p12
```

This command merges the PKCS12 keystore containing the CA certificate to the PKCS12 keystore containing the additional and its private key:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ***/ca.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass '***' -destkeystore ***/additional.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -deststorepass '***'
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bragolgirith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959499/2868801) was and (so far) remains correct for the standard cryptoprovider SunJSSE -- a lone cert without a special bag attribute, which OpenSSL doesn't write, is not recognized in Java.

However if you use the [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org) provider, it does not require the bag attribute. In fact for many years it didn't even write the attribute when *creating* pkcs12; as of 1.71 about 2 years ago it does write it but does not require it when reading. However Bouncy does (write and) require the friendlyname attribute, which SunJSSE writes but does not require, and which openssl does not write by default so you must specify it explicitly. Thus

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in cert.pem -caname reallyme -out file.p12
```

creates a file that Java *using Bouncy* treats as containing a trustedCert. Doing so in a program usually isn't hard, but to get keytool to use Bouncy I haven't found anything simpler than

```
keytool -list -keystore file.p12 -storetype bcpkcs12 -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath /path/to/bcprov.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the truststore you generated was non-empty?

I've found that running the openssl command that you ran wil generate an empty truststore.

This is confirmed by checking its contents with:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore truststore.p12
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the last command (pkcs12 -export -nokeys) the file is NOT empty, but Java (or rather SunJSSE) wrongly treats it as empty, as thoroughly explained seven years ago, so your keytool command doesn't show the contents.