# created java truststore.p12 using only openssl

Tags: java, openssl, java-security

I'm generating self-signed certs as part of an installation process and don't want to install the JDK in order to get keytool (which, undeniably would  [make the problem easier](http://www.jhack.it/mediaWiki/index.php/OpenSSL%26Co#Trusted_certificates_in_PKCS.2312.2FP12.2FPFX).

Per: [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959499), the PKCS12 truststore bag has to have the required attribute '2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1' in order for the JRE to use it as an accepted truststore.

[This article](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a471/inserting-custom-oids-into-openssl.aspx) covers adding OIDs to the certificate request.  The approach looks promising, but I keep getting the following error

```
Error Loading request extension section req_ext
...:X509 V3 routines:do_ext_nconf:unknown extension:../crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:82:
...:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:../crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:47:name=java_trusted_ca, value=yes
.
.
where relevant parts of openssl.conf are:
oid_section = OIDs
[ OIDs ]
java_trusted_ca = 2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1
[ req ]
req_extensions = req_ext
[ req_ext ]
java_trusted_ca=yes
```

I need help setting the attribute so that the attributes contain:

```
MAC Iteration 1024
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1024
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: microsoft it ssl sha2 (baltimore cybertrust root)
    ------------------- THIS PART BETWEEN HERE --------------
    2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>
    ------------------------ AND HERE -----------------------
```

Comment: You want to add a PKCS12 bag attribute, not a CSR attribute. Unfortunately, this does not seem supported by openssl (yet), see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6684