# Creating PKCS12 file to use as java trust store

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to create a PKCS12 file containing only a certificate (no private keys). I am using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ca.crt -out server-ca.pfx -name server-ca -nokeys
```

I can successfully use this pkcs12 file with curl and it validates my server certificate.

If I try to use this file as a trust store in java, I get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, with message: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found.
```

I am using this file with:

```
val trustInput = new FileInputStream(".../server-ca.pfx")
val trustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
trustKeyStore.load(trustInput, "123456".toCharArray())
trustInput.close()

val trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
trustFactory.init(trustKeyStore)

val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
context.init(null, trustFactory.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom())
```

However, if I create a JKS keystore containing the `ca.crt` file and then convert it to a pkcs12 file, my java application validates the server certificate properly, using the same code.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server-ca.jks -destkeystore from-jks.pfx -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12
```

What `openssl` command do I need to use to create a pkcs12 file containing a single certificate that jvm accepts as a valid trust store?

Comment: Try `openssl pkcs12 -info -in server-ca.pfx` to see what's actually in your PFX file. Maybe your cert isn't actually there.

Comment: The certificate is there and it has the same fingerprint as in the jks file.

`keytool -keystore server-ca.jks -list   
[...]

server-ca, 15-May-2019, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): E4:94:E2:FB:7C:6F:F3:9A:29:AF:AD:7E:D3:98:F7:AB:EF:50:D1:5C
`

`server-nginx 130  openssl pkcs12 -in server-ca.pfx -info -cacerts | openssl x509 -noout -sha1 -fingerprint                     
[...]
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 1
Certificate bag
SHA1 Fingerprint=E4:94:E2:FB:7C:6F:F3:9A:29:AF:AD:7E:D3:98:F7:AB:EF:50:D1:5C
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this using the sun security provider. Since I am using bouncy castle already, I initialized the trust store using the BC provider and now everything works properly.

```
val trustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC")
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959499/5302210) by user [Bragolgirith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620458/bragolgirith) explains the problem. [This](https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer/issues/11#issuecomment-190404396) is an answer on one of the linked GitHub Issues where your solution is explained as well.
I think another solution that adds the relevant special attribute to the certs in the trust store would still be preferable.