# Why does Java's keytool show no entries for a PKCS12 trust store created with openssl?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I'm unsure why Java's `keytool` thinks my `.p12` keystore is empty.

If I create a new self-signed cert and place it in a `truststore.p12` pkcs12 keystore with `openssl`, like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=www.example.com" -sha256

# This prompts for a password, I used 'changeit'
openssl pkcs12 -export -out truststore.p12 -nokeys -in cert.pem
```

And then view the contents of `truststore.p12` with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in truststore.p12 -nodes

MAC verified OK
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=www.example.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=www.example.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Everything looks good. But when I try to view same file with keytool:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore truststore.p12 -storepass changeit -storetype PKCS12
```

I get this from `keytool`:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

Why?

For context, I am generating my own self-signed CA and issuing client & server certificates with it.  I have some Java applications that need to consume my CA trust chain (via `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` command-line args, but fail because I suspect keytool thinks it's empty).

Now, `keytool` WILL show `privateKeyEntry` if I include the corresponding private key of the cert. However, I'm creating a trust store (i.e. a CA Chain) and it shouldn't have any private keys in it; only public certificates.

Comment: This is not going to solve your problem but [this is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766935/creating-p12-truststore-with-openssl).

Comment: Can you just use keytool to create the P12 truststore?

Comment: What made you use `-storepass changeit`?  There's nothing there that has set a password. Remove that option.  You don't have a password on that truststore, and you don't need one.

Comment: @user207421: yes there is. His `openssl pkcs12 -export` actually put in a (PBE) cert even though SunJSSE ignores it, plus _all_ pkcs12 created by OpenSSL (and all other sw I've seen) _always_ has PBMAC even if there is actually _no_ data inside.

Comment: As I added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935820 it works if you add `-caname x` on the `openssl pkcs12 -export` and you use `keytool -list -providername BC -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath path/to/bcprov-jar ...` (I think you can omit the latter two if bouncy is configured in your `JRE/{lib,conf}/security/java.security` file.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK but not a password of 'changeit'.

Comment: @user207421: how do you know? He doesn't say what he entered to the prompt, and even if he posted a screenshot (which consensus opposes) it wouldn't show the pw. (Note: I apologize for being old and lazy; please change pronouns if appropriate per corporate policy.)

Comment: Running `openssl pkcs12 -export` will prompt you for a password.  `changeit` was the password I used, I'll update the question to clarify that

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I would if all possible like to avoid using any proprietary tooling... I don't want to force anyone into having an installation of Java as a requirement to run my openssl app. 

By the way, that is the exact error this Java application is throwing (empty `trustAnchors`) when it starts up.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'll try out specifying the Bouncy Castle provider and see what happens!

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959499/5302210) to the question linked by [President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk) also answers this question. A special attribute must be set for a certificates in a PKCS12 formatted file to be accepted as TrustStore (without Private Keys). You can convert around and like this add this attribute to the certificate as described [here](https://www.jhack.it/mediaWiki/index.php/OpenSSL&Co) at the end of the page.

Comment: I know its been an year but did you get any solution around this problem?

Comment: @SpaceyBot not really, what I ended up doing was using a Docker container with Java installed to generate the PKCS12 truststore with keytool and write to the host disk.  Pretty jank but it worked since my client's system supported Docker.

Comment: @heez, Yes I was also successful when I generated my truststore using keytool instead of openssl. The problem is with the missing "Bag Attributes" which will be added by default when generated with keytool. In your case, that'd be `keytool -import -alias somekey -file cert.pem -keystore truststore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit`

Comment: @SpaceyBot, Hi, what are the missing attributes? can't we just add them to be able to generate a functional truststore in openssl?