# Creating keystore for given RSA keys

Tags: encryption, rsa, keystore, private-key

I have private key and public key, both .pem files and I have to generate Java key Keystore for them.

I tried different openssl commands but I'm getting "unable to load certificates" error.

One such command I tried was:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in [path to certificate] -inkey [path to private key] -certfile [path to certificate ] -out testkeystore.p12
```

But I got:`*unable to load certificates*`

Please help to generate the keystore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914898/why-does-javas-keytool-show-no-entries-for-a-pkcs12-trust-store-created-with-op?noredirect=1#comment121810251_68914898

Comment: Do you have a public-key or a certificate? Those are different. To create a PKCS12 usable by Java (and most other things also) you must have a privatekey and a certificate (specifically, an X.509 certificate, although nowadays that mostly goes without saying) and NOT just a publickey. @PresidentJamesK.Polk: #68914898 is about creating a truststore with _cert only_, not a keystore with a privatekey which is radically different.

Comment: Yes, I have a public key. So, basically I have public and private keys both. 

I got public and private keys from my server. From where do I need to get X.509 certificate?
@dave_thompson_085

Comment: You need to generate a **self signed certificate** in the first step using openssl req -key domain.key -new -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt. In the next step you are been able to import the private key and the certificate to a PKCS12 keystore. Beware... the certificate is valid for one year, maybe you extend it using -days 3650 (10 years).

Comment: @MichaelFehr I used command you suggested to create cert file and then created a keystore but after that if I try to extract private key from key store, it does not match with the original private key provided.

Comment: 'Does not match' how? Just the PEM representation, or are the actual fields (n,e,d,p,q,etc) different? If your input keyfile is dashed 'BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY' and your 'extracted' is just 'BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY' (no RSA), those are supposed to _look_ different, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255521/private-key-differs-when-creating-a-pfx-container-and-then-extracting-it-from-it  (from only 2 days ago!) If either your input, output, or both is/are encrypted, see my comment there.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it works fine for me now, thanks for looking into it